# Liquibase Sybase - dbo.DATABASECHANGELOG not found error

Tags: database, spring-boot, sybase, liquibase

I have just started using Liquibase for Sybase ASE migrations. The problem that I am having is the database server we are connecting to is having two databases db_main and db_local. db_main contains the wrapper procs and references db_local procs. In the connection string we are passing db_main. Like this -

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:jdts:sybase://serveraddress/db_main
spring.liquibase.default-schema: dbo
```

When the liquibase spring boot application starts it creates DATABASECHANGELOG and DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK table in the db_main database and updates them properly when the change is isolated to db_main database only. However, when we are trying to update an existing procedure in db_local database which is something like this -

```
use db_local
go
if object_id('employee_table_i') is not null
  drop ....
...
```

Liquibase throws exception -

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: dbo.DATABASECHANGELOG not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists
```

Here is my changeSet -

```
<changeSet author="12345" id="1">
    <sqlFile path="classpath:/liquibase/features/employee_proc_i.sql" endDelimiter="go"/>
</changeSet>
```

I believe the issue is happening because the proc has -

> use db_local

If I update the changeSet to below it works fine -

```
<changeSet author="12345" id="1">
    <sqlFile path="classpath:/liquibase/features/employee_proc_i.sql" endDelimiter="go"/>
    <sql>use db_main</sql>
</changeSet>
```

but I am not sure if this is the only way it can be done or there is any better way of doing it. Any help or guidance is appreciated.

I am using liquibase-core version - 4.4.1 with spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out.

1. Remove `use db_local` from the procedure
2. Use 3 object reference in our sql changeset. For example: `drop table db_name.schema_name.object_name`
3. Remove `<sql>use db_main</sql>` from the changeset.